# React Native: How to make HTTP request when app is backgrounded?

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

To simplify my problem: I have an ecommerce app that uses geofencing to detect when to prepare an order:

```
    BackgroundGeolocation.onGeofence(geofence => {
      this.props.prepareOrder();
    });
```

The thing is, prepareOrder() makes an HTTP request to my server. I've noticed that it doesn't actually make the request until my app is foregrounded.

Is there a way around this? It is very likely that my app is backgrounded when they enter the geofence and I need to make a request.

======

The more complex version is here: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/816. I'm using redux-sagas and it doesn't seem like `yield call` is being called. But I'm not sure if it's a redux-saga thing or something with making HTTP requests in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Same here... It's not a redux-saga problem, it's a more general problem with ReactNative apps working in background: the JS Thread appears to be frozen when app is in background for a long time (especially on iOS when screen is shut down)

the behavior is different between iOS & android, and also depends on OS version. Still, We're building an application that needs constant geolocation in foreground & background, we tried doing it with sagas and we saw it didn't work : we would stop receiving locations after some time. Watching at our logs, we would see that all the ReactNative logs we had would stop too. Hence our wild guess on "maybe the OS stops all the ReactNative context, for energy reasons

So we moved our background code into native :

- HTTP POST in a custom RN Native Module when app is in background on iOS
- Headless JS on android.
  (it seems to be the solution others have chosen too, like https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation)

it works!